# How to change the default username of mysql?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have just installed Mysql server and Mysql workbench in my Ubuntu 14.04. Now I want to change the default username(root) in the setup connection wizard. Is that the username for mysql server? Is the password in wizard is different from the password given during the mysql server installation?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run following command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbTest.* To 'user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

If you are running the code/site accessing MySQL on the same machine, hostname would be localhost.

Now, the break down.

`GRANT` - This is the command used to create users and grant rights to databases, tables, etc.

`ALL PRIVILEGES` - This tells it the user will have all standard privileges. This does not include the privilege to use the GRANT command however.

`dbtest.*` - This instructions MySQL to apply these rights for the use onto the full dbtest database. You can replace the * with specific table names or store routines if you wish.

`TO 'user'@'hostname'` - 'user' is the of the user account you are creating. Note: You must have the single quotes in there. 'hostname' tells MySQL what hosts the user can connect from. If you only want it from the same machine, use `localhost`

`IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` - As you would have guessed, this sets the password for that user.

Hope it helps